# Overload Generator

Tags: c#

Is there an app or website where I can input parameter info (types and variable names), their defaults, and have it generate all the combinations of method overloads?

I have a class where the constructor can take in five parameters of different types. The parameters get mapped to properties, none of which have public setters. Each parameter has a default value.

I want my class to have overloaded constructors for all the various combinations of the parameters (ranging from no parameters to any and all combinations of the five parameters). To make it more confusing, one of the parameters can be passed in as a specific type or as a string, and I want the various combinations of overloads to take that into consideration.

Update:

I agree this design may not be the best. The class in question is one I'm using in a similar fashion to the PropertyMetadata class of WPF's DependencyProperty. A value is assigned for the property backing, and a new instance of the metadata class is passed in at that time. It's forcing my hand to create this cascading series of constructor overloads. Example:

```
private ModelProperty<UserModel, string> firstNameProperty =
  RegisterProperty(p => p.FirstName, new ModelPropertyMetadata(**** lots of overloads here ****));
public string FirstName
{
     get { return GetValue(firstNameProperty); }
     set { SetValue(firstNameProperty, value); }
}
```

Maybe that's not the best design. I could possibly extend ModelPropertyMetadata to new classes which describe specific overloads, but that just seems like its pushing the problem somewhere else. Any thoughts on how to make this design better?

Comment: If you need to do this, you are doing something wrong. Rethink your design.

Comment: How so? I've seen many classes coming from the BCL with an exorbitant number of overloaded constructors. Can't think of any off the top of my head, but I know they exist.

Comment: sounds like a case of bad design.  why do you need this?

Comment: Are you building a framework? Many of the multiple overloads are legacy from .NET 1.0/1.1 where there were no other options.

Comment: You're not likely going to find a tool to do this for you, it's not something you _need_ to have. It's also pretty trivial to cook up something to generate all the permutations that you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [optional parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) - these should help you avoid multiple overloads and still provide multiple ways to call a constructor. This is a .NET 4.0 feature.

Comment: This answers my original question nicely, but I'm still curious if anyone has any thoughts on how to improve my design (given the example I included).

Comment: @mbursill - The problem with expanding a question as you have is that it is now a new question and answers pertaining to the original may be meaningless. Perhaps, next time, ask a new question.

Answer (score 2):

Why not using optional parameters?

```
public MyClass(String myVar = null, Int32 v0 = 5, ...) { .. }
```

You can call the ctor this way:

```
new MyClass(v0: 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of one, but might I suggest you create a simple type that holds the parameters and has the defaulting logic and you pass that type into your class as what your suggesting will be difficult to maintain.